# Nested array comparison with var_export and serialize fails due to key types

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, phpunit

I have a PHPUnit test that fails: `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Notice : Array to string conversion`
Because I'm comparing large arrays:

`$this->assertEquals(array(), array_diff($expected, $result));`

I've tried to change it so that i compare serialized strings, but it also fails, even if I use var_export($result) and put it in $expected as is.

```
PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException : Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
Expected :a:1:{s:8:"somename";a:2:{s:13:"property_name";s:8:"somename";s:15:"possible_values";a:2:{i:0;i:1;i:3;i:2;}}}
Actual   :a:1:{s:8:"somename";a:2:{s:13:"property_name";s:8:"somename";s:15:"possible_values";a:2:{s:1:"0";i:1;s:1:"3";i:2;}}}
```

I realize that there is most likely issue with integer/string conversion of keys somewhere inside 'possible_values' nested key. I've tried different combinations of possible_values keys, eg. '0'=>1, 0=>1, 0=>"1" etc.

Can you recommend a **better nested array comparison** method, or explain how to make it pass.

var_export of $result gives me:

```
array (
  'somename' => 
  array (
    'property_name' => 'somename',
    'possible_values' => 
    array (
      '0' => 1,
      '3' => 2,
    ),
  ),
)
```

P.S. `$this->assertEquals($expected, $result);` also fails in PHPUnit, even though when I open difference in PHPStorm, it says that contents are identical

```
PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException : Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I've resorted to:

```
$expected = 'a:1:{s:8:"somename";a:2:{s:13:"property_name";s:8:"somename";s:15:"possible_values";a:2:{s:1:"0";i:1;s:1:"3";i:2;}}}';
$this->assertEquals($expected, serialize($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use string keys in `$expected` to match `$actual` or convert them in the test. BTW, how are you creating `$expected`? If you're typing it manually into the test, just use string keys in the first place.

```
assertEquals(self::fixPossibleValuesKeys($expected), $actual);

static function fixPossibleValuesKeys($array) {
    $original = $array['somename']['possible_values'];
    $fixed = array();
    foreach ($original as $k => $v) {
        $fixed[strval($k)] = $v;
    }
    $array['somename']['possible_values'] = $fixed;
    return $array;
}
```

> **Note** This is *horrible* code to have to put into your test! You're much better off either changing the code under test to return something more useful (unless string keys *is* what you want) or building a test fixture with the correct expected values from the start. Your tests should perform as little logic as possible since that code will be untested.